# YouTube Pop up empty Modal

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to code a pop up modal with an embed YouTube video but my modal is empty. I'm using Bootstrap and have two separate sections and javascript.
When the modal appears it is blank. Have I coded it wrong?

Here is my code.

```js
$(function() {
  // Auto play modal video
  $(".video").click(function () {
    var theModal = $(this).data("target"),
    videoSRC = $(this).attr("data-video"),
    videoSRCauto = videoSRC + "?modestbranding=1&rel=0&controls=0&showinfo=0&html5=1&autoplay=1";
    $(theModal + ' iframe').attr('src', videoSRCauto);
    $(theModal + ' button.close').click(function () {
      $(theModal + ' iframe').attr('src', videoSRC);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<!-- REMOTE HELP VIDEO -->
  <section id="remote-help-video" class="p-5 text-center">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="container p-2">
          <a
            href="#"
            class="video"
            data-video="https://www.youtube.com/embed/fRpYMzXXqEU"
            data-toggle="modal"
            data-target="#videoModal"
          >
            <i class="fa fa-play"></i>
          </a>
          <h1>See How Team Viewer Works</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- VIDEO SECTION MODAL -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="videoModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span>&times;</span></button>
          <iframe src="" height="350" width="100%" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The code works when this is the only function but I have other functions before it in my script file.

The full JavaScript file;

```
$('.slider').slick({
  infinite: true,
  slideToShow:1,
  slideToScroll:1,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 4000
});

var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([36.367, -5.23], 11);
L.marker([36.367, -5.23]).addTo(mymap)
        .bindPopup("<center>We are happy to serve:</center> <b>Estepona, San Luis de Sabinillas, Manilva, Guadiaro, Soto Grande</b> and all surrounding areas").openPopup();

L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoicGF1bHNlYWwiLCJhIjoiY2prbXlpZjN5Mjl1YzNzcWh1MGpkYjd0YyJ9.q6m5a0rQF5cfEtn6Lb6H4Q', {
  maxZoom: 18,
  attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
    '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
    'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
  id: 'mapbox.streets'
}).addTo(mymap);

$("form").submit(function(e) {

  var error = "";
  if ($("#email").val() == "") {
    error += "The email field is required.<br>";
  }
  if ($("#subject").val() == "") {
    error += "The Subject field is required.<br>";
  }
  if ($("#message").val() == "") {
    error += "The message field is required.<br>";
  }
  if (error != "") {
    $("#error").html('<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><p><strong>There were error(s) in your form:</strong></p>' + error + '</div>');
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
});

$(function() {
  // Auto play modal video
  $(".video").click(function () {
    var theModal = $(this).data("target"),
    videoSRC = $(this).attr("data-video"),
    videoSRCauto = videoSRC + "?modestbranding=1&rel=0&controls=0&showinfo=0&html5=1&autoplay=1";
    $(theModal + ' iframe').attr('src', videoSRCauto);
    $(theModal + ' button.close').click(function () {
      $(theModal + ' iframe').attr('src', videoSRC);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: i just copied your code and put it in a fiddle and it appears to work as is... https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/166814/ Is there an error you're getting in the console?

Comment: it's all working..`<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/fRpYMzXXqEU" height="350" width="100%" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

Comment: Yeah strange. It works well if I remove the other javascript from my script.js file but when the other code is before it it doesn't work?

Comment: well i just went ahead and tried figuring out what your dependencies were and put them in this fiddle. The only thing that was causing the error was there was no container with a 'mapid' https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/166985/ if you scroll down to the bottom where the modal trigger is this still works. all i added to the html was `<div id='mapid'></div>`

Comment: Granted, the map stuff looks weird and you have to scroll down to the bottom by clicking on the window scroll bar. but the point is the modal with the embedded video still works with the added javascript in front

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by changing the order of my javascript file, I moved the Modal code to the top of the .js. Probably not the best way to do things but it worked.

```
$(function() {
  // Auto play modal video
  $(".video").click(function () {
    var theModal = $(this).data("target"),
    videoSRC = $(this).attr("data-video"),
    videoSRCauto = videoSRC + "?modestbranding=1&rel=0&controls=0&showinfo=0&html5=1&autoplay=1";
    $(theModal + ' iframe').attr('src', videoSRCauto);
    $(theModal + ' button.close').click(function () {
      $(theModal + ' iframe').attr('src', videoSRC);
    });
  });
});

$('.slider').slick({
  infinite: true,
  slideToShow:1,
  slideToScroll:1,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 4000
});

var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([36.367, -5.23], 11);
L.marker([36.367, -5.23]).addTo(mymap)
        .bindPopup("<center>We are happy to serve:</center> <b>Estepona, San Luis de Sabinillas, Manilva, Guadiaro, Soto Grande</b> and all surrounding areas").openPopup();

L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoicGF1bHNlYWwiLCJhIjoiY2prbXlpZjN5Mjl1YzNzcWh1MGpkYjd0YyJ9.q6m5a0rQF5cfEtn6Lb6H4Q', {
  maxZoom: 18,
  attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
    '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
    'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
  id: 'mapbox.streets'
}).addTo(mymap);

$("form").submit(function(e) {

  var error = "";
  if ($("#email").val() == "") {
    error += "The email field is required.<br>";
  }
  if ($("#subject").val() == "") {
    error += "The Subject field is required.<br>";
  }
  if ($("#message").val() == "") {
    error += "The message field is required.<br>";
  }
  if (error != "") {
    $("#error").html('<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><p><strong>There were error(s) in your form:</strong></p>' + error + '</div>');
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
});
```